# AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android

the error that i m getting :-

```
 04-08 00:37:48.540: E/AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.collision/
com.android.collision.GameViewActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: 
can't instantiate class com.android.collision.GameViewActivity; no empty constructor
```

other deatils of the coding portion and i have to extend my main activity class by SurfaceView

my manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.collision"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".GameViewActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

And my mail activity is :-

```
public class GameViewActivity extends SurfaceView {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


 public GameViewActivity(Context context) {
       super(context);


 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your activity must extend an Activity class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: i need to extend my activity class by SurfaceView

Comment: if you need to use SurfaceView, you need to add it to your Activity's layout, do not subclass it.

Comment: thanks for your attention on my question but i dont know how to add it in my activity class

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

so do it like this

```
public class GameViewActivity extends  Activity
```

or you can extend any activity from your project eg.

```
public class GameViewActivity extends  GameActivity
```

Comment: i need to extend my activity class by SurfaceView

Comment: so that file  has no Activity ? it should have extend that activity  not class .

Comment: ok then how to add the SurfaceView in my activityclass after extend it by Activity